# Dropdown buttons on input groups not displayed properly

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create and input group with an input text and two buttons, one of which is a dropdown button. With two regular buttons the input group is correctly displayed bu with the dropdown the corners are not properly drawn.

Regular buttons (displays OK):

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username with two button addons" aria-describedby="button-addon4">
  <div class="input-group-append" id="button-addon4">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

With dropdown (displays incorrectly):

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username with two button addons" aria-describedby="button-addon4">
  <div class="input-group-append" id="button-addon4">
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/goncalomarrafa/ecg6o4m5/3/

Is this a "feature" of Bootstrap or I am doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure a fix, but you can switch the position on the dropdown and button in the second example; that makes it work, but might not be correct for your use case.

Comment: It is likely not supposed to be used this way, from a UI/UX perspective: if you inspect the rule for nested buttons in an input group, you can see the bootstrap designers explicitly excluded dropdowns from the `border-top-right: 0px; border-bottom-right: 0px` rule. I have a feeling that this is because visually the dropdown makes sense as the right-most call-to-action on an input group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your code to the following and fixed the 'curved' portion of the dropdown button using CSS:

Look at the `.no-right-border` and `.btn-drop-down` CSS.

```
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.btn-drop-down {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.no-right-border {
  border-right: 0 !important;
}
```

You html for the drop-down button should be:

`<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle btn-drop-down no-right-border" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</button>`

Notice I added the classes to the class attribute on the button element.

Changing `border-radius` to 0 and `border-right` to zero get the desired effects.